# Is the following proof of Borel Cantelli lemma with Markov Inequality valid

Tags: probability, analysis, measure-theory

The Borel-Cantelli Lemma states that if $(E_n)_{n\ge 1}$ is a set of events such that $$\sum_{n\ge 1} \mathbb{P}(E_n) < \infty$$

Then with probability 1, there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N$, $E_n$ does not happen. In other words, finitely many events happen.

My approach: let $1_{E_n}$ be the event that $E_n$ happens. Then $\sum_{n\ge 1} 1_{E_n}$ is the number of events that happen. By linearity of expectations (on nonnegative variables)

$$\mathbb{E} [\sum_{n\ge 1} 1_{E_n}] = \sum_{n\ge 1} \mathbb{E}[1_{E_n}] < \infty$$

Applying Markov Inequality,

$$ \lim_{m\to\infty} \mathbb{P}(\sum_{n\ge 1} 1_{E_n} > m) \le \lim_{m\to\infty}  \frac{\mathbb{E}[\sum_{n\ge 1} 1_{E_n}]}{m} = 0$$

Therefore, with probability 1, $\sum_{n\ge 1} 1_{E_n}$ is finite.

I'm sure there is something wrong with this proof, but I don't know what is wrong. Would someone please kindly tell me?

Comment: Your inequality does not even make sense. But you only need minor corrections. Can you spot the two mistakes you made?

Comment: I fixed a typo if that's what you're looking for

Comment: What does Markov's inequality say?

Comment: Where did you use the hypothesis?

Comment: Sorry for that typo. Tell me if there are any issues that I haven’t fixed.